# What is bias weight in Matlab perception

Tags: matlab, neural-network

**what is bias weight in Matlab perception**

I implemented the OR gate perceptron using nntool. Its works ok but what is the contribution of bias weight in case of the nntool perceptron.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not a tutorial service; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret the perceptron as a linear classifier, then you can interpret the the perceptron itself as an algorithm saying if your input lies on one or the other side of the line. The bias parameter is then the distance of this computed line from the origin.